# How much trouble will NVIDIA Optimus graphics switching cause my Linux installation?

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, graphics

I'm about to get a new laptop, and I want to dual-boot Windows and Linux on to it.  I noticed that a lot of laptops you can buy come with Optimus graphics switching installed.

I like the idea of being able to switch between onboard graphics and discrete graphics depending on what software I'm running.  On the other hand, I've heard that Optimus isn't supported for Linux, so that could cause a lot of problems.

I'm going to have to make a decision whether to get a machine with Optimus or not to.  Here is my question; I hope that it'll help me choose:

- How much of a headache is it going to cause me to run Linux on an Optimus machine?  How difficult will it be to make it work initially, and what sort of problems might I run into later on?

Comment: All major distros come with the nvidia-optimus/bumblebee in their repos.  You'll be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a laptop (Dell XPS 15) with nVidia Optimus. It already works: basically the only need I had to install was *bumblebee*. Most distros will have a package to wrap the needed configuration.

I tried some apps (mostly games under Steam) and they seemed to have acceleration. I didn't try using e.g. CUDA.

The only thing that doesn't work as intended is the HDMI output, which is linked to the nVidia card and therefore doesn't work in dual-head mode (I can get video output [by using some kludges](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/NVIDIA_Optimus_and_HDMI_Output_Configuration), but they're a separate X display and I can't drag windows there).

EDIT: The HDMI can work with Nouveau, but then you lose the power management and have some graphics glitches.